# T-SQL CASE behavior in a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Thanks in advance for your interest!

I want to send a work order status parameter (@WOStatusCriteria) to a stored procedure (in SQL Server 2016) for use in a SELECT.  I want to query on status of either "R" (Released) or "F" (Firm) OR BOTH, depending on the need at the moment.

As the possible status codes are C, F, R, U and X, I wrote the following CASE in a WHERE clause, hoping that if R or F were not explicitly sent in the parameter, both R and F statuses would be returned by virtue of the NOT C, NOT U, NOT X phrase.  It doesn't work, and I'm looking for a solution that does.  Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

```
(wo.STATUS = CASE 
    WHEN @WOStatusCriteria = 'R' THEN 'R'
    WHEN @WOStatusCriteria = 'F' THEN 'F'
END)
AND (NOT wo.STATUS = N'C' AND NOT wo.STATUS = N'U' AND NOT wo.STATUS = N'X')
```

Comment: Read erland's discussion (and everything else) [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your current code should work if you add:

```
ELSE wo.STATUS
```

to your CASE expression.

since `wo.STATUS` will always equal `wo.STATUS`, the CASE will be ignored and the other conditions will be evaluated.

Comment: Thanks very much!  That worked.  I believed that the answer was in an ELSE, but wasn't sure how to go about it.